# Showing SkipException Error

Tags: java, testng

I am skipping a few test cases with TestNG successfully with `IInvokedMethodListener` but it does not print out the error message I have provided. It is showing `"Test Ignored"` without any further message that makes debugging hard.

Is there a way to write into that specific test case console space indicating its error?

**EDIT** - The tests are unable to be skipped. However, the message does not get displayed on the console (in each individual test cases). It only displays **Test ignored.** I am hoping to have some useful error messages for better debugging in the future.

```
@Override
public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod iInvokedMethod, ITestResult iTestResult) {

    Class target = iInvokedMethod.getTestMethod().getInstance().getClass();
    String targetName = target.getName();

    ... some processing logic to decide whether to skip
    throw new SkipException("Throwing exception here to skip test");
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a sample of what you have as code so far.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan Thanks for replying. Added my beforeInvocation code.

Comment: "Test Ignored" is coming from where?

Comment: The test ignored is shown on the intellij console log within each test case.

Answer (score 0):

It is annoying and I have not found a solution, just a work-around: I print the message first then call the throw.  I have a method skipTest(message) and in there write out message and then throw(new SkipException).